# Are "not uncommon" and similar phrases double negatives? Should their use be avoided?

Tags: word-usage, negation, double-negation, litotes

When I think of double negatives I think of phrases that grate on the ears, like:

> I'm not going to do no homework.
>
> I'm never going to not go visit Graceland.

There are some phrases that appear to technically be considered a double negative, but seem more common and are, in my opinion, actually pleasing to the ear. And I've seen such uses in newspaper articles, magazine articles, and other edited content.

I'm referring to phrases like:

> It's not uncommon for two people to meet serendipitously.
>
> Baseball is not unlike golf - both are boring to watch without a beer in hand.
>
> It's not unusual to be loved by anyone.

Are the above examples of double negatives? Should their use be avoided?

Comment: this usage nowadays is *not uncommon* ;) - so I'd not feel it needs to be avoided.

Comment: Avoid their use if you are unsure about how to use them.  But if you are not unsure, then go ahead!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your first explicit question, I would say they are [double negatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative):

> A double negative occurs when two forms of negation are used in the same clause.

To answer the second question, I would say the use of [litotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) is perfectly acceptable.

> Litotes is a form of understatement, always deliberate and with the intention of emphasis. However, the interpretation of negation may depend on context, including cultural context. In speech, it may also depend on intonation and emphasis; for example, the phrase "not bad" can be said in such a way as to mean anything from "mediocre" to "excellent."

The respective Wikipedia articles (linked to and excerpted above) give a lot of good information.  I would like to emphasize the potential ambiguity in litotes, in that the intensity of the double-negative-as-positive ranges from "mildly positive" to "resoundingly positive".

Finally, see [this other EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6124/does-not-uncommon-mean-common) covering the specific example of *not uncommon*.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the use of litotes for understatement, e.g. "a not inconsiderable task".

Answer (score 6):

It's a rhetorical technique called *litotes*, and it goes back at least as far as Homer:

> οὔτε γάρ ἔστ᾽ ἄφρων οὔτ᾽ ἄσκοπος...
> ("he is neither unthinking, nor
> unseeing")

If it's good enough for St. Paul ("I am a Jew, from Tarsus in Cilicia, a citizen of no ordinary city" -- Acts 21:39) it's good enough for, well, you.

**EDIT**
I forgot my favorite example, *Harold and Kumar Go To White Castle*, which contains several exchanges like

> Kumar: You're worthless
>
> Harold: (dejected) I'm not worthwhile

John Y. points out that not all litotes fits the OP's model of "not un-".  In fact, the best (St. Paul, John Cho, [Sade](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WcWHZc8s2I)) don't.  I think it's, ahem, not unreasonable to say that the "not un-" style can sound plodding and even pompous.

(While I'm wandering off topic: none of this should be interpreted as defense, even by way of faint condemnation, of the real double-negation of the "we don't need no education" variety, which is Just Plain Wrong.)

Comment: "no ordinary city" instead of "a strange city" or "an extraordinary city".

Comment: Fair enough, as an example of litote (I found it in Wikipedia's [litote entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) just before deleting my original comment).  Still, it was worth pointing out because it doesn't have the "not un-" construction.  It may not be obvious that *ordinary* is meant as a negation of something here.

Comment: While posting my own answer, I missed the window for editing my comment.  I wanted to change all instances of "litote" to "litotes", as I'm sure *litotes* is a valid word, but I'm not sure *litote* is.  Apparently *litotes* can be used as a singular or plural as needed.  (Maybe this should be its own EL&U question.)

Comment: Don't let the -s ending fool you, "litotes" is an uncountable noun, like "sarcasm" or "hyperbole".  There's no "a litote" any more than there is a "two sarcasms".

Comment: @Malvolio: Ah, the comparison to "sarcasm" and "hyperbole" makes it clear, thanks.  (You may then want to make a small edit to the phrase "not all litotes fit" in your answer.)

Comment: +1 for litotes, -1 for “Just Plain Wrong”. There's a [question dedicated to “we don't need no education”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8777/) on this very site.

Comment: +1/2 for the Greek! And +1/2 for Just Plain Wrong, whose capitals should leave no doubt as to its irony, and make it clear that the writer is no fool and understands the debate. // May I ask why your accented letters are small capitals?

Comment: I barely read Greek, let alone write it: the Iliad fragment was C&P from Wikipedia.  As for the capitals in my own writing indicating irony, yes and no.  I am not much of a prescriptivist -- and I certainly realize the well-deserved ill-regard prescriptivism is held in -- but if "We don't need no education" means the same thing as "We need no education", I have to ask what the extra "don't* is supposed to mean.  Not to criticize Roger Waters, of course: his lyrics scans better and is truer to character.

Comment: @Michael Lorton  Saki used "Sarcasms" in his story "Morlevera" "He was always talking sarcasms". However this was put in the mouth of a lower-class child in London, so it may not have been intended as Standard English.

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, no, it is not a double-negative.  At least not the normal sense of the word.  A double-negative refers to using two negatives, as in not and no, when trying to convey one meaning where you actually end up saying the opposite.  "It is not uncommon" is a negation of a word with a negative meaning.

Think of it this way.  Can you say "I'm not going to do no homework" in another way that makes your meaning clearer?  Obviously you can.  "I'm not going to do any homework."  Can you say "It is not uncommon" in a way that makes your meaning any clearer?  Nothing comes to mind for me.  You could say, "It is ordinary", but that has a slightly different meaning to me.

Comment: +1 for making the distinction between syntactic negation and semantic negation. Two syntactic negations are what is meant by "a double negative". Directly negating the meaning of a word, regardless of the positive or negative value statement in the meaning, isn't a double-anything.

Answer (score 2):

Having two negation terms together intended as negation is common in colloquial and non-standard dialects of English, but it is prescribed against in Standard English. For example:

> There ain't no chitlins left in the skillet.

which translated to Standard English is

> There are no fried pig intestines remaining in the frying pan.

or

> There aren't any fried pig intestines remaining in the frying pan.

(ignore for the moment that "ain't" is also prescribed against in SAmE)

This is primarily what one (your school teacher) referred to when they said "Double negation is forbidden".

But using two negatives in order to create a logical positive, (or weak non-negative), while cognitively laborious, is perfectly allowable. The phrase

> not uncommon

...is 'legal' English and is intended to mean common or rather more accurately "somewhat more frequent than rare, i.e. not rare, but I don't want to go so far as to say frequent".

So one can use two negatives when the intention is to mean a positive.

So for your examples, the first one is OK in some varieties of non-standard English (but of course grates, as you said, in Standard English). Your second example is -not wrong- just slow to make sense of and most likely was intended to mean "I will go to Greenland".

Comment: I wouldn't say *chitlins* were pig *skin* though...

Comment: @Dusty: ...oh..right...fixed.