# What does the phrase "none too dissimilar" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

I have heard the phrase *none too dissimilar* used many times. Based on context, it seems to mean *similar*, or perhaps *very similar*.

Does *none too dissimilar* have a different meaning that I am missing?

Example:

> The book and the movie were none too dissimilar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What constitutes a double negative?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31671/what-constitutes-a-double-negative)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/607837/2085).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[None too](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/none-too)* means *not very*, so the sentence means that the book and the movie were not very different.

Comment: Is it very formal or can I use it in a casual conversation?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: If I were you, I would *only* use it in casual conversation! In all Googles millions of indexed books it only occurs 30 times - some of which are hyphenated, suggesting the writer knows he's using an unusual form of words. Personally I think it's an extremely clumsy double negative, and I would point out that that double negatives in general are often associated with "low-quality" speech/speakers.

Answer (score 3):

*None too dissimilar* means practically nothing.

All three words are [negatives](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), i.e they all generate [NPIs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), and the relations between them are hardly spelled out.

*None* is a negative existential quantifier meaning *not one* or *not any*. Logically **¬(∃x)**.

*Too* is a quantificational adverb with complex syntax. If something is *too P* then it is **P** to a degree that causes some negative outcome. Logically **(∃x) (Degree(P(x)) ∧ (Degree(P(x)) ⊃ ¬S)**.

*Dissimilar* is a symmetric negative predicate with two arguments -- either of which can be subject if the other is object, which is not the norm. The overt negative states that the degree of similarity is low; I won't bother with the logic here; the point is, it's complicated.

Hence these can be combined in any number of different ways, and it's simply not clear what this speaker or writer meant by the phrase. This process of [overnegation](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1926) seems destined to go on forever, as Larry Horn has pointed out.

Comment: Your attempted translation could do with some work, though.  *None* here is clearly a simple negation: *too* does not require an existential quantifier in any definition: and the semantics of a double negative are neither complex nor ambiguous.

Comment: True. _None too_ is mostly an idiom for _not very_, and that reduces it to _duplex negatio confirmat_. But it's not obvious to English learners (who constitute most of our readership here, I think) that it **is** an idiom, nor what it means, which generally argues against using it.

Comment: I've always thought the common idiom *[arrive] none too soon* is rather odd. It invariably means *just soon enough/in the nick of time*, but most other usages (e.g. *none too smart*, etc.) tend to imply *not smart enough* as much as *not very smart*.

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP's sentence is OK as long as it's meant with a degree of sarcasm i.e. if the expectation is that the book and movie were supposed to be different, then their description as "none too dissimilar" is making the point that they were indeed similar.