# Do negatives work algebraically?

Tags: grammaticality

Does a triple negative make a positive?
eg "Ain't nobody gonna eat none of my jellyroll."

Comment: Are you talking about colloquial usage (where that sentence means *nobody's eating any of my jellyroll*) or literal and syntactical usage (where that sentence means *there is somebody who will eat none of my jellyroll*)? *Colloquially*, double negatives don't actually mean a positive—they mean a negative.

Comment: mmm in algebra a triple negative makes a negative, no? Your sentence isn't really a triple negative because the nobody and none will be interpreted as agreeing with the ain't, not as being negatives in their own right. If you have a genuine triple negative. as in *it turned out not to be the case that there was nobody who didn't like her*, then yes that does have a positive meaning, as in algebra.

Comment: No, they do not. See [this ELL question & answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/95834/triple-negation-what-does-this-aint-no-place-for-no-hero-mean/95835#95835) which covers very similar territory.

Comment: There is no such thing as a triple negative. Only a triple misinterpretation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What constitutes a double negative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31671/what-constitutes-a-double-negative)

Answer (score 1):

In "standard" English dialects, negating a negation makes a positive statement. *I am not typing nothing* means *I am typing something*. And by this same logic, *I am not not typing nothing* would mean *I am typing nothing*. A memorable example of this is a line from *Bill and Ted's Bogus Journey*: "That was non-non-non-NON-heinous!" In other words, *that was heinous*.

However, numerous non-standard English dialects use double negation as a form of emphasis. *I didn't eat none of that food* means *I really did not eat any of that food*. Just as in standard dialects, the addition of extra negatives follows a consistent logic. In this case, instead of additional negation, it's additional emphasis. "Ain't nobody gonna eat none of my jellyroll" would mean, *no one is going to eat my jellyroll and I mean it!*

Comment: I've never been convinced by the 'emphasis' idea. In *ain't nobody gonna eat none of my jellyroll*, I think *nobody* and *none* just mean *anybody* and *any*. It seems to me that in a given register people use either *nobody* or *anybody* - I just can't envisage someone who thinks they're both available in the same register and *nobody* can therefore be used to add emphasis.

Comment: No, *I am not typing nothing* would *not* mean the same thing as *I am not not typing nothing.*

Comment: Oops.  Good catch @JasonBassford.

Comment: @Minty I disagree. *Ain't* ***nobody*** sounds much more emphatically *negative* to me than *ain't* ***anybody***. This is simply because *nobody* and *none* are negative words.

Comment: but no more emphatic than "Is nobody..."?

Comment: ...in fact "ain't anybody" is almost an invitation.

Comment: But do you ever say *ain't nobody*? Google tells me that *ain't anybody* appears in Tom Sawyer, but I'm not sure I've ever heard it live, and if I did, I would probably think someone was doing their best English because they were on TV or whatever. More than happy to be wrong about that but *there ain't anybody* just doesn't sound to me like something anyone would ever come out with.

Comment: @Minty, you may be right.  "Ain't anybody" may not be possible in the dialects that use "ain't nobody." But the better comparison might be "ain't nobody gonna eat this" and "nobody's gonna eat this." The former sounds more emphatic than the latter. But I don't speak any of these dialects and don't have a deep understanding of them.

Comment: @Juhasz I think that's a different issue - *there's nobody who's can get below 9s for 100 metres* is more emphatic than *nobody can get below 9s...*, but it's not to do with negation.

Comment: @Minty *I* don't say *ain't nobody*, because I'm too much about the grammar. But, having said that, it *does* sound more emphatic to me—and I can appreciate it when I hear other people saying it. I also think that *informal* language generally sounds more emphatic than *formal* language. So, *nobody can* ***does*** sound more emphatic to me than *there's nobody who can*, not only because it's missing the positive *is*, but also because it's simply shorter and more to the point. In general, more words means less emotional decisiveness.

Comment: @JasonBassford well a bit more googling suggests that some people do say *there ain't anybody*, so if those same people also say *there ain't nobody*, there could be a difference of emphasis. That said, the uses of *it ain't anybody* that I found seemed pretty emphatic, so I'm still a bit sceptical.