# The difference between 'I don't know nothing else' and 'I know nothing else'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, agreement, negative-polarity-items, negative-concord

What is the difference between the following?

> I don't know nothing else

and

> I know nothing else

There's a *don't* in the first sentence, however both sentences translated the same in google translator. So, are they used interchangeably?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What constitutes a double negative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31671/what-constitutes-a-double-negative) Mitch's answer doesn't need repeating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard Englishes (all of them) do not allow so-called "double negatives" like your first example, which is ungrammatical in them.

Many speakers throughout the Anglosphere use forms like your first example in their ordinary speech: in their non-standard varieties of English, the form is grammatical, and has the same meaning.

All English speakers understand the first (to mean the second) unless they are being deliberately perverse; but many never use such forms.

I advise a learner never to use the first form unless you understand the social implications of using such a variety of English; but expect to hear and understand it.

Comment: Agreeing with Colin Fine - *I don't know nothing else*  in standard English would be *I don't know anything else.*