# Is there a right and wrong way to use double negatives?

Tags: double-negation

Somewhat related to [How can double negatives "has a respectable history as a rhetorical device for emphasis" when they're harder to understand?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/551500/211388) I am noticing that that there is an increase in use of [double negatives](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/31671/211388) in speech.

*"I didn't say nothing"* or *"I don't want nothing"* is very common.  One friend of mine who keeps doing this has the mickey taken out of him by returning with *Oh, so you did say something then"*.

I hear it a lot in pop and R'n'B songs. Take for example, *If I ain't got you* by Alicia Keys.

The chorus has *"But I don't want nothin' at all"* in it, and the outro has *"Said nothin' in this whole wide world don't mean a thing"*.

So, with my friend's predicament in mind, is there a right and wrong way to use double negatives?

Comment: This is a large topic, and has been extensively studied. But it's impossible to give a simple answer without restricting it to a particular type of double negative in a particular dialect. Double negatives are found in many forms of English, including a lot of American dialects, and you'll find a lot of material online. The Wikipedia article is probably a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative

Comment: The kind of double negative that has a 'respectable history' is something like _not impossible_ - see that related question.

Comment: @KateBunting I've seen that question and agree that they are OK as they don't follow the same pattern as the examples in my question. Those double negatives have both negatives next to each other.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey sorted

Comment: There are all kinds of ways of using negation, and some of them can cancel and some of them don't, though "a right and wrong way to use" them doesn't quite cover the territory. Perhaps you might enjoy learning [more about negatives](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) before you count and judge them.