# How to understand "You don't get no coffee"?

Tags: meaning, double-negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are double negatives ever appropriate in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31667/are-double-negatives-ever-appropriate-in-english)

> "You don't get no coffee"

I feel like the above sentence is a bit confusing to understand. What's the exact meaning of it? Should we say we `can` get coffee, or we simply `can't`?

Comment: @Kit thanks so much for the link. Really a good one :)

Comment: Well, it was @Robusto, but I'm sure he says "You're welcome."

Comment: @Kit: For the record, I usually say "no problem."

Answer (score 1):

It means "You don't get any coffee." Whoever has the coffee isn't going to give you any. You can't have any.

Although not accepted as grammatically correct, "no" instead of "any" is often said, especially in the southern United States. Still, a worldwide famous example in pop culture is from a UK band, ["(I Can't Get No) Satisfaction" by the Rolling Stones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28I_Can%27t_Get_No%29_Satisfaction). To further illustrate its common usage, simply typing "don't get no" into Google has yielded [47,800,000](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22you%20don%27t%20get%20no#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22don%27t%20get%20no%22&pbx=1&oq=%22don%27t%20get%20no%22&aq=f&aqi=g2g-ms1g-m1g-ms1&aql=undefined&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5222l8372l0l14l11l0l0l0l0l329l2626l0.3.6.2l11&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=72e3de3f4256b86e&biw=1275&bih=702) results.

Comment: I guess a little bit of body language could have helped understand it a lot :)