# Is it correct to say " have been not" in English?

Tags: grammar

For example , is it correct to say that " The service has been not available since 3 days ago ". And, Is the meaning of it different from "The service has't been available since 3 days ago"

Edit: changed "have" to "has"

Comment: You can not use "since" in that way. The service HAS not been available FOR three days.  The serviceS HAVE NOT been available FOR three days.  Regarding "since" - just don't use it, it's too confusing. If you wanted to use "since": It HAS been three days SINCE the services WERE available.

Comment: Or 'the service has not been available since Monday'. But as regards the original question 'has been not avialable' sounds awkward and unusual. It's better to say 'has not been available'.

Comment: +Joe, does it mean I should not say, "I have not eaten since three days ago"? "I have not been eating since three days ago" is bad? Where did you get that rule? Pls explain.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical. Jonathan Swift (author of *Gulliver's Travels*) wrote satirically: *"After having inquired into and considered the state of the war, in which the part your majesty has borne appears to have been not only superior to that of any one ally, but even equal to that of the whole confederacy …"* Surely nobody would suggest Jonathan Swift didn't write good English. Is it advised? Unless you know what you're doing, most definitely ***not***.

Answer (score 3):

No, both versions are grammatically incorrect on multiple accounts, but mean the same thing. You should say either:

> *The service has not been available for 3 days.*

Or:

> *The service hasn't been available for 3 days.*

Comment: Use "since" to specify a date

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are wrong, in both cases, *the service* is singular, and so should the verb be.
I'll assume that *have't* is a typo for *haven't*.

That said, in sentence "The service has been not available since 3 days ago" is parsed like this:

> [The service] [has been] [not available] [since 3 days ago].

Now, *not available*, as a single concept, is idiomatically rendered as **unavailable**. Although *not available* means the same, it sounds "off" since the normal expression is *unavailable*.

So, although the version with *not available* is grammatically correct, a better version, that would sounds more natural, would be:

> The service has been unavailable since 3 days ago.

This sentence means exactly the same as

> The service hasn't been available since 3 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the logical validity of "have been - since".

- Animals have been domesticated since the dawn of civilization.
- Humans have been domesticating animals since the dawn of civilization.
- Could you get some real food? I have been eating cupcakes for lunch since we arrived three days ago.

By induction, the logic of the following sentence is valid.

- The service has been erratic since 3 days ago.

And, therefore the logic of the following is also valid

- The service has been available since 3 days ago.
- The service has not been not available since 3 days ago.

Consider the following and compare with [I can't not be pregnant](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171202/i-cant-not-be-pregnant).

- The doctor told me my pregnancy was a false alarm. I have invested too much emotionally, as well as in the baby clothes. I need to be pregnant. I cannot not be pregnant.

Therefore, the 2nd sentence in the following, though unusual, should be perfectly valid ...

- The service has been unavailable since 3 days ago.
- The service has been not available since 3 days ago.

~ [QED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.).